# calculate x ^ (1 / y) mod m fast (modular root)

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

How can I solve x ^ ( 1 / y ) mod m fast, where x, y, m are all positive integers?

This is to reverse the calculation for x ^ y mod m.  For example

party A hands party B agree on positive integer y and m ahead of time

party A generates a number x1 (0 < x1 < m), and hands party B the result of x1 ^ y mod m, call it x2

party B calculates x2 ^ ( 1 / y ) mod m, so that it gets back x1

I know how to calculate x1 ^ y mod m fast, but I don't know how to calculate x2 ^ (1 / y) mod m fast. Any suggestions?

I don't know how to call this question.  Given x ^ y mod m is called modular exponentiation, is this called modular root?

Comment: To me this algorithm does not seem right - take a note that x^y is always integer given x and y are integers but x ^ (1/y) is not which means that by using this operation you will go out of your finite field which is bad. Though maybe root operation has some different definition in modular arithmetic.

Comment: as `x1^y mod m = x2`, so `x1^y = mq + x2`.  How did you get `x1` from `x2^(1/y) mod m` is equal to `x1`?

Comment: I think you should call this question "breaking RSA cryptography", isn't it? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I think you're asking this question: Given y, m, and the result of x^y (mod m) find x (assuming 0 <= x < m).

In general, this doesn't have a solution -- for example, for y=2, m=4, 0^2, 1^2, 2^2, 3^2 = 0, 1, 0, 1 (mod 4), so if you're given the square of a number mod 4, you can't get back the original number.

However, in some cases you can do it. For example, when m is prime and y is coprime to m-1. Then one can find y' such that for all 0 <= x < m, (x^y)^y' = x (mod m).

Note that (x^y)^y' = x^(yy'). Ignoring the trivial case when x=0, if m is prime Fermat's Little Theorem tells us that x^(m-1) = 1 (mod m). Thus we can solve yy' = 1 (mod m-1). This has a solution (which can be found using the extended Euclidean algorithm) assuming y and m-1 are coprime.

Here's working code, with an example with y=5, m=17. It uses the modular inverse code from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

```
def egcd(a, b):
    if a == 0: return b, 0, 1
    g, x, y = egcd(b%a, a)
    return g, y - (b//a) * x, x

def modinv(a, m):
    g, x, y = egcd(a, m)
    if g != 1:
        raise AssertionError('no inverse')
    return x % m

def encrypt(xs, y, m):
    return [pow(x, y, m) for x in xs]

def decrypt(xs, y, m):
    y2 = modinv(y, m-1)
    return encrypt(xs, y2, m)

y = 5
m = 17

e = encrypt(range(m), y, m)
print decrypt(e, y, m)
```

RSA is based on the case when m is the product of two distinct primes p, q. The same ideas as above apply, but one needs to find y' such that yy' = 1 (mod lcm((p-1)(q-1))). Unlike above, one can't do this easily only given y and m, because there are no known efficient methods for finding p and q.